# Run supervisord with custom configuration file from startup

Tags: centos, startup, supervisord

I'm using [this article](https://rayed.com/wordpress/?p=1496) as a source to get me half way there, but I cannot figure out how to run supervisor with a custom config file path.

When I want to run supervisor manually, I just do:

`supervisord -c /home/test/_app/supervisord.conf`

When I implemented the auto start up script, it runs the default supervisor config file which is located in `/etc/` directory.  I don't want to use that one because it separates it from the core project folder and makes it hard to maintain and keep track of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by simply deleting the default `supervisord.conf` file and then making a sym link with that default location and my custom conf file path.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In `/etc/rc.d/init.d/supervisord`, add `prog_opts` variable like this:

```
prog_opts=" -c /home/test/_app/supervisord.conf"
prog_bin="${exec_prefix}/bin/supervisord"
```

Then in `start()` function, change the call to:

```
daemon $prog_bin --pidfile $PIDFILE -- $prog_opts
```

Comment: Nah that doens't seem to work, it's actually not even starting up.  Do you know where logs would be stored for `init.d` startup services?

Comment: you should redirect them since they go directly to `stdout` :D